# Can't use debugger for xamarin android project: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly Mono.Posix

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

After upgrading my visual studio 2017 to `15.2v (26430.12)`

`Xamarin.Android SDK 7.3.1.2 (9dbc4c5)`

Can't use the debugger anymore. The project builds successfully and deployment finishes but then this error happens:

> Could not load file or assembly Mono.Posix

Full error message:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elvis' answer is correct.  However in addition to copying the file Mono.Posix.dll to the correct location, you also need to unblock the file by right clicking on the file, selecting properties and checking the unblock box. After that you need to restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 13):

This is a [Known Issue](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56787). The root cause is lacking of `Mono.Posix.dll` file under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin.VisualStudio\`.

So, to fix the problem, you can download the dll file from [attached file](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/attachment.cgi?id=22522) and copy it to the up mentioned location.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to;

- Disable "Use Shared Runtime" on the Android project.
- Delete the App from the emulator.
- Delete the Mono runtime from the emulator
- Clean -> Rebuild -> Deploy without debugging and then starting a debug session

Later on I could switch "Use Shared Runtime" back on and it has been working since.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has affected two different PC's of mine. At first I first thought it was related to upgrades to VS when it occurred on my first PC. However, it has impacted my second PC after I upgraded from 23.3.0 to 25.3.1 without updating VS.

I am going to avoid 25.3.1 and revert to 23.3.0.

BTW I tried woelliJ's solution but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary workaround:

1. Download the missing [Mono.Posix](https://dl.xamarin.com/uploads/bo4kicqj0a4/MonoPosix.zip) file and unzip the archive.
2. Right-click the Mono.Posix.dll file in Explorer and select Properties.
3. Check the Digital Signatures tab to ensure the file shows a valid Xamarin Inc. signature.
4. At the bottom of the General tab, if an Unblock checkbox appears, enable it and select OK. (This checkbox appears depending on how the file was downloaded.)
5. For Visual Studio 2017, copy the Mono.Posix.dll file into the “Xamarin.VisualStudio” extension directory. For example, for a default installation of the Enterprise edition, copy the file into:
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin.VisualStudio
6. For Visual Studio 2015, copy the file into the “Xamarin\Xamarin” extension directory:
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Xamarin\
7. Quit and restart Visual Studio.