# i cant create emulator in Visual Studio 2019 xamarin forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

when i want to create emulator this popup showed =>

[[image: image of Message Box Error]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUNyQ.png)

> Could not load file or assembly Mono, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
>   , Public Key Token = 0738 9 f 132 ed 756' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

I already installed the latest version of mono file inside this location
C:\Program Files ( x 86 )\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\Common 7\IDE\Extensions\ Xamarin . Visual Studio

Comment: wich VS2019 preview version do you use?

Comment: Please check the solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364657/cant-use-debugger-for-xamarin-android-project-system-io-filenotfoundexception).